# Proving that the variance is non-negative

Tags: probability-distributions

$$(E(X))^2 = \left( \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf(x) \, dx \right)^2 \le \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2(f(x))^2 \, dx \le \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^2f(x) \, dx = E(X^2)$$

Because of cauchy-schwarz inequality and $f(x) \le 1$. Is my solution correct?

Comment: and similarly for discrete type

Comment: By definition, Variance is $E\left[(X-E[X])^2\right]$.

Comment: Why does $f(x) \leq 1$? take the exponential distribution with parameter 5. Then $f(x) = 5 e^{-5x} \mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}^+}(x)$ that is $> 1$ for some $x$

Comment: @Tryss isn't $f(x) \le 1$ necessary for $f$ to be a p.d.f?

Comment: I think i misused cauchy's inequality as I don't remember it anymore, but i remember a similar inequality. sorry

Comment: $f(x)≤1$ isn't even true for uniform distributions, if the support is small.

Comment: If $xf(x)$ is a real number then the integral will be real and the square of a real number is nonnegative.

Comment: @lulu but why is then $v(x) \ge 0$?

Comment: @George : No. Take the uniform distribution  on $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$, then $f(x) = 2$ on  $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$

Comment: so how do I prove it then?

Comment: Variance is non-negative for the reason I gave in my first comment.  It is the expectation of a non-negative quantity.  As an exercise, it's good to verify that the definition I gave is equivalent to the one you implicitly used ($E\left[X^2\right]-E\left[X\right]^2$)

Comment: @lulu thanks I got it. but if I want to use the second definition how do I prove it?

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz works fine, just apply it to $X\sqrt{f(x)}$ instead of $X$  Note:  even though $f(x)$ can get above $1$, it still can't ever be negative!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\mu=\operatorname{E}(X)$.  The variance is $\operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname{E}((X-\mu)^2)$.  That is non-negative because it's the expectation of a nonnegative random variable.  Now notice that
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname{E}((X-\mu)^2) \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname{E}(X^2 -2\mu X + \mu^2) \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname{E}(X^2) - 2\mu\operatorname{E}(X) + \mu^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname{E}(X^2) - 2\mu^2 + \mu^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname{E}(X^2) - \mu^2.
\end{align}
If the question is how to prove that that last expression is nonnegative, then one way to prove it is by seeing, as above, that it's equal to the first expression above.

Comment: it is intuitive but not entirely clear to me why expectation of non negative random variable is non negative.

Comment: @Abhay If the random variable is non-negative, how could its expectation -- sampled/integrated over the space in which it's non-negative -- be negative?